# How do I select all the text in an editText after the user is finished typing in it?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-edittext, user-experience

I have an EditText with some dummy text in it. When the user finishes typing I want to be able to have all the text selected.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rx's debounce to do that,

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
        .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe { textChanged: CharSequence? ->
            Log.d(
                "TAG",
                "Stopped typing!"
            )
            editText.selectAll()
        }
```

Comment: editText.selectAll()  : this is what truly worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference for your edittext :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(/* edittext id */);
```

Attach a text changed listener on it :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
        //get your final string here 
        String str = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```